# scala 2.11: how do I redirect console output to file

Tags: scala

`Console.setOut(printStream)` method is deprecated in scala 2.11. Is there any other alternatives for this now? How do I redirect console output to file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the deprecation note in the [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Console$@setOut(out:java.io.OutputStream):Unit) states, use [`Console.withOut`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Console$@withOut[T](out:java.io.OutputStream)(thunk:=%3ET):T), which takes an `OutputStream`:

```
import java.io.{File, FileOutputStream}

val fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/path/to/file.txt"))
Console.withOut(fos) { println("print this to the file") }
```